# Google Apps Script with Slack interaction button

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a bot that sends and reply to messages in Slack and everything is working great until I tried to implement interaction buttons, the buttons actually work but when I pressed them they don't send a payload back to my POST method (e.parameter.payload is empty). I tried testing it and set the interactive url to https://dev.oscato.com/ url and the payload is being sent correctly, so I'm not sure if there is something I'm missing in the setup of my bot. Below is my code for the button and the send method, I don't think there's anything wrong with the code tho else it won't send a payload to the Optile site.

```
function sendButtonMessage() {
  var message = JSON.stringify([{
    //アタッチメント部分
    "title": "Button Select",//　アタッチメントのタイトル
    "text": "Please select a button.",//アタッチメント内テキスト
    "fallback": "Button pressed!!!",//ボタン表示に対応してない環境での表示メッセージ. 
    "callback_id": "test",
    "color": "#00bfff", //左の棒の色を指定する
    "attachment_type": "default",
    // ボタン部分
    "actions": [
      {
        "name": "approve",
        "text": "はい",
        "type": "button",
        "value": "entertainment"
      },
      {
        "name": "reject",
        "text": "いいえ",
        "type": "button",
        "value": "entertainment"
      }
    ]
  }]);

  return message;
}


function sendMessageAsAttachment(message, params) {
  var payload = {
    "token": token.SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    "channel": params.event.channel,
    "attachments": message
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "payload" : payload
  };

  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(SLACK_CHAT_URL, options);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to recreate your issue. Did you publish a new version of your app to accept the changes? How are you checking the `e` values?

Comment: Yes, I did publish a new version of my app and accepted the changes. I check the e values by using console.log(). The e value is not empty, but it does not contain payload in it after I pressed the button. Below is my POST code.

function doPost(e) {
    console.log("payload: " + JSON.stringify(e));
}

Comment: I solved the problem! If I put var params = JSON.parse(e.postData.getDataAsString());  before I read the payload, the payload will not show! Put it after and it will show!